# Jinja2: Assign array value to a variable

Tags: python, arrays, jinja2

I'm passing an array object from a view in my Flask server to the jinja2 template. Let's say the name is aList. Then i am trying to assign array values to a variable.

in Flask:

```
aList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

in the template:

```
{% set temp= aList[0] %}
{{temp}}
```

But this is not working from Apache server.

O/P:Nothing

Working fine if I directly use array {{aList[0]}}, is this a limitation for Jinja2 ?

Comment: what to you get as result of this {{aList[0]}}

Comment: That syntax is accurate. The issue is likely in the Flask code.